# Запуск второго цикла после закрытия приложения

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение с 2-мя активити. В первой - одна кнопка с названием Меню номер один. Нажимаешь, попадаешь во второе активити, и в методе `onCreate` выполняется цикл.

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    public ArrayList<Integer> Arrayl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);

        Arrayl = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int a = 1; a < 8; a++) {
            Arrayl.add(a);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(Arrayl);// перемешиваем
        Log.d("","ТУТ:"  +Arrayl.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent gotoanotheractivity = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(gotoanotheractivity);

    }
}
```

Далее, нажимаешь кнопку Главное меню и попадаешь снова в первое активити, где есть кнопка Меню номер один.

Так вот, **задача**: когда я во второй раз зайду во второе активити, то должен выполнится уже вот такой цикл:

```
Arrayl = new ArrayList<>();
for (int a = 8; a < 25; a++) {
     Arrayl.add(a);
}
Collections.shuffle(Arrayl);// перемешиваем
Log.d("","ТУТ:"  +Arrayl.toString());
```

Подскажите, хоть идеей как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

В первой активити можно создать флаг, который будет означать, впервые ли запускается вторая активити или нет.

При запуске второй активити этот флаг можно передавать в `intent`, а в методе `onCreate(...)` второй активити доставать этот флаг из интента и, в зависимости от этого флага совершать те или иные действия.